# Open2.4.5 Android Crashes when I call Mat

Tags: java, android, opencv, crash, mat

This issue is been driving me crazy for days now. I'm trying to use opencv android the latest package. Everything is inserted and I don't have any errors, until I run the project on android and that's when it crashes. When I call a simple code like, Mat m = new Mat(); the app crashes, I saw some other people has the same problem but somehow they managed to fix it, here is my code, maybe it's something stupid I can't see! All I really need is Matrix library, I tried Jama and jblas but they work to some point but then they crash too, and they're very slow.

```
 package com.ece.facerecog;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;'
 import java.util.Arrays;

 import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
 import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
 import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
     import org.opencv.core.Mat;

import com.ece.facerecog.utils.UIHelper;


//import org.jblas.DoubleMatrix;


  //import Jama.Matrix;
     import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
  import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 //import android.graphics.Matrix;

  import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Environment;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.GridView;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class Face extends Activity {
private Bitmap bitmap;
private int f = Crop.k;
private ImageView tv;

   private static final String    TAG                 = "OCVSample::Activity";

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};
  //    @Override
   //   public void onResume()
    //  {
  //        super.onResume();
  //        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_5, this,                           k                  mLoaderCallback);
    //    }

private Bitmap ReadImage1(String fBitmap) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/preprocessed");
    File file = new File(myDir , fBitmap); //or any other format supported
    UIHelper.displayText(this, R.id.textView1, file.toString());

    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;        
        Bitmap bitmap =            `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),options); //This gets the image `       
        return bitmap;

        } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               UIHelper.displayText(this, R.id.textView1, "Doesn't exist");
        }

        return bitmap;
    }



   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.face);

Log.i(TAG, "Trying to load OpenCV library");
if (!OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_5, this, mLoaderCallback))
{
  Log.e(TAG, "Cannot connect to OpenCV Manager");
}


ImageView tv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Bitmap bmp = ReadImage1("/Image-" + f+ ".jpg");
tv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
Mat m = new Mat();
```

}
}

`

Here's the log error,

```
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat:()J
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:441)
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at com.ece.facerecog.Face.onCreate(Face.java:147)
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-13 23:14:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV functions such as `Mat` have to be invoked in either a `thread` or `AsyncTask`, I think. I faced the SAME issue for AGES without help.

For you to avoid crashes, you could declare `Mat m` as a global variable and initialize it in the `AsyncInitialization` block of OpenCV.

Something like this :

```
 public class Face extends Activity {
 private Bitmap bitmap;
 private int f = Crop.k;
 private ImageView tv;
 Mat m;
 private static final String    TAG                 = "OCVSample::Activity";

  private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
@Override
public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
    switch (status) {
        case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
            m=new Mat();
        } break;
        default:
        {
            super.onManagerConnected(status);
        } break;
    }
}
};
```

If it still crashes, I would suggest you execute whatever function you're trying in an `AsyncTask` like in my [project](https://github.com/torcellite/imageComparator). `Mat` functions however can be declared without the risk of the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception in OpenCV functions. Functions called in the UI however experience this. At least this is what I've seen.

Comment: I'm not sure why you got a vote down! but you are right, if I do it in the Async, it won't crash. So Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Can you vote the answer up? I've voted the question up.

Comment: I don't have enough reputations yet,I will when I got the "15 reputation"!

Answer (score 4):

I just faced the same problem and found another solution:
You can use another activity to call your activity ("Face"), like some introduction screen with a button that starts your activity. If you initialize OpenCV in this introduction activity (same way you did in your activity) you can use OpenCV functions in the next activity without any problem...

This way you don't have to declare OpenCV variables as a global variables and initialize them in the AsyncInitialization block of OpenCV.